# Tuple<> and IComparable<>

Tags: .net, tuples, icomparable

Consider the following innocent looking method:

```
Random random = new Random();
public int MySemiRandomComparer<T>(T a, T b)
{
    if (typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(a, b);
    else
        return random.Next(-1, 2);
}
```

However, this code fails:

```
MySemiRandomComparer(
       Tuple.Create(new SomeNonComparableClass()), 
       Tuple.Create(new SomeNonComparableClass()));
```

Specifically, it fails with the following `ArgumentException`:

> At least one object must implement IComparable

In other words, `Tuple<>` declares that it is `IComparable` when in fact it is not guaranteed in runtime. This could have been prevented by constraining the type parameters to be `IComparable` as well, but then `Tuple<>` could not have been used with non-`IComparable` classes, and maybe then we'd be forced have `Tuple<>` and `ComparableTuple<>` or something similar.

Is this a bug in `Tuple<T>`, or is `MySemiRandomComparer` to blame ? Or maybe it's a bit of both, where a concious design decision was made to keep things simple ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide a small but complete sample.

Comment: Aha. You need to use two *different* instances in the two calls to `Tuple.Create`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Sorry about that, I revised the question to convey that fact.